# Silverlight Javascript Console "Failed to Invoke" IE security issue

Tags: javascript, silverlight, internet-explorer

I have Silverlight 5 Application, which send some debug information to Console, using helper class. Code of JavascriptConsole is very simple:

```
public class JavascriptConsole
{
    static HtmlWindow window = HtmlPage.Window;
    static ScriptObject console = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("console") as ScriptObject;
    public static bool IsConsoleAvailable()
    {
        return !(bool)window.Eval("typeof(console) == 'undefined' || typeof(console.log) == 'undefined'");
    }
    public static void Error(params object[] parameters)
    {
        if (!IsConsoleAvailable()) return;
        console.Invoke("error", args: parameters);
    }
}
```

This code works fine on Google Chrome on ANY environment. It also works fine on IE on my localhost environment. However if I execute this SL application in IE on any other environment (except my local) I have exception "Failed to invoke: error", no additional information provided.
[image]

I use the same IE browser for local and not local environment. When I execute console.error('my error') from IE Dev Tools Console - it works fine. So it looks like some Silverlight Javascript Bridge security issue in IE.

It also works fine for window object accessed from Silverlight, so code

```
window.Eval("console.error('my error message')");
```

works fine too

Answer (score 0):

Don't use eval. 
Make sense to refactor code:

instead tons of code in

```
public class JavascriptConsole
```

do simple method

Silverght:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
      HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("log", data);
}
```

JavaScript: So Javascript can be placed inline(not good) or as script link on page.

```
function log(data) {
    // verify that console exists and log whatever needed.
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: that's not really simple - I will have to change JS of the hosting page

Comment: it might be only problem , if you don't own your hosting page. if so I agree

Comment: btw: I have just tried to run sample like yours. so I work fine for me. But be aware I have Win8.1 + IE11. Maybe there in issue with Internet Setting for plugins like Silverlight. anyway. I believe solution posted above will work for any cases.

Comment: As I mentioned my sample works fine on local environment. It will not work only when you deploy it to other server and access client on browser of your machine

Comment: I see. have you played with settings? 
Silverlight needs to run in trusted, Try and adjust the Interenet security levels?